# Selenium upload for MAC

Tags: macos, selenium, upload, autoit

I am learning Selenium Java Automation Testing. But I'm having trouble using AutoIT to upload files. As far as I know, AutoIT only supports Windows and not MAC, so you know which plugin should I use to upload for MAC? Help me, please, thanks so much!

Comment: is it file uploading ? if there's any input that has attribute as `type='file' `you can do `send_keys`

Comment: In my project, not attribute as type='file', Do You know another way ? Please

Comment: Is URL public ?

Answer (score 0):

- No, AutoIT is not supporting Mac, and it's for windows.
- Don't click the upload button.
- you can set the filename on `send_keys()` and then click on the upload button

  ```
   element = driver.find_element_by_id("fl_element_id");
   element.send_keys('/your/Path/to/file.csv');
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#fl_element_id span[name=upload]').click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your support Rajith Kariyawsam . But some case, we can't use sen_keys() to upload because I not find attribute "type=file". You know another way as Java Robot Class ?

Comment: Okay then you can refer this: [How to upload files in Selenium Webdriver in MAC OS] (https://learn-automation.com/upload-file-in-selenium-in-mac) Please refer to comments also tin hat URL --> robot.delay(1000) is recommended by some guys.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following working with the Robot class on macOS Ventura 13.4.1:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class uploadFileScript {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException {
    // Initialize webDriver     
    System.setProperty("webdriver.geckodriver.driver",  
        "<DRIVER_LOCATION>");       
    WebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // Cater for page load      
    firefoxDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

    // Navigate to web site     
    firefoxDriver.get("https://www.grammarly.com/plagiarism-checker");
        
    // Cater for page load      
    firefoxDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        
    // Maximize window      
    firefoxDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        
    // Scroll operation using Javascript Executor       
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) firefoxDriver;
        
    // Scroll Down page browse option       
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)");
        
    // Allow processing time after scroll       
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Find upload file element     
    WebElement chooseFile = firefoxDriver.findElement(
                        By.xpath("(//span[@class='o9viu-text'])[2]"));
        
    // Click on element     
    chooseFile.click();

    // Allow processing time after click        
    Thread.sleep(2000);
        
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(                          
                "/Users/<USER_NAME>/Desktop/<FILE_NAME>.doc");
        
    // Copy to clip board       
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
        
    // Create an object of Robot class      
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    // CMD + TAB is needed to regain focus          
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);       
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);        
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);     
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);      
    robot.delay(1000);

    // Open Goto window CMD+SHIFT+G     
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);       
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);      
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);      
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);     
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);        
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);        
    robot.delay(1000);

    // CMD + TAB is needed to regain focus          
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);       
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);        
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);     
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);      
    robot.delay(1000);
        
    // Open Goto window CMD+SHIFT+G     
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);       
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);      
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);      
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);     
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);        
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);        
    robot.delay(1000);

    // Paste the clip board value CMD+V     
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);       
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);      
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);     
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);        
    robot.delay(1000);

    // Press Enter key to select file       
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);      
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);        
    robot.delay(1000);
        
    // Paste the clip board value CMD+V     
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);       
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);      
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);     
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);        
    robot.delay(1000);

    // Press Enter key to select file       
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);      
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);        
    robot.delay(1000);

    // Press Escape key to close the Goto window and Upload window      
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);     
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);       
    robot.delay(1000);

    firefoxDriver.close();
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Successfully uploaded file", "uploaded"));     
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).